# HttpURLConnection works on emulator but not on the device

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to experiment the HttpURLConnection to get some XML from a server.
This is the code I'm using:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String myConn = this.getString(R.string.myConnection);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL mySite = new URL(myConn);
        URLConnection connection = mySite.openConnection();
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;         

            in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

            String myString = convertStreamToString(in);
            tv.setText(myString);           

    } catch (IOException ex) {} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        httpConnection.disconnect();
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the emulator this code works and i can see the stream on the TextView...

On my device I can't see anything (3g connection)..

Did I miss something?

thanks

Comment: Do you get any error on Logcat? That should give some idea what is wrong.

Comment: If you're using a 4.0 device, it won't let you request data from the web without using an AsyncTask (or similar).

Comment: No I can't see any error in the log..... And I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S with 2.3.3..

Comment: So do i need to use the AsyncTask?

Comment: The same code works on emulator 2.2 but it doesn't work on emulator 2.3

Comment: Irrespective of what the system will let you get away with, you should definitely not be doing I/O in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Now i modified the code and I use an Async Class object to perform the connection in the background.. But it still doesn't retrieve the stream from the site. since the same code works on 2.2 but not in 2.3 probably is there anything different that i should set up in the code?

Comment: Ok... I used the HttpClient instead of the HttpURLConnect to perform the same operation and now it works... Anyway I would really know why the code above didn't work. Is t because i have to wait some kind of response from the php page (like the 200 on HttpClient)?

Answer (score -1):

By using AsyncTask You can solve this problem.